# How to analyze which site has most numbers

Tags: visualization

I am trying to determine which site in our organization is in greater need of upgrades to SEP 12, so when I run a query to count, I get these type of numbers

```
Group       Windows_SEP_11  Mac_SEP_11  Windows_SEP_12  Mac_SEP_12
Arizona\A   417                  29              219         6
Arizona\B   380                  20              282        15
Arizona\C   340                  30              383        507
Arizona\D   310                  104             186        857
Arizona\E   307                  74              403        243
Arizona\F   285                  171             522        14
Arizona\G   269                  1               559        41
```

However, when I find percentages, I get these numbers

```
Group          Win_Sep_11_%   Mac_SEP_11_%  Windows_SEP_12_%    Mac_SEP_12_%
Boston/Site 1   100               0                0               0
Boston/Site 2   100               0                0               0
Boston/Site 3   94                0                0               5
```

And obviously, percentage isn't good indicator because Boston/Site 1 has only 3 computers, Boston/Site 2 only has 4 computers, etc.

What is the best way to analyze data? I ultimately need a visual of sites that have

1. many computers, and
2. a great need for upgrades to SEP 12, i.e. if there are more computers with SEP 11 than SEP 12.

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: There is no "best" here because you haven't clearly defined your criteria, and only you can do that. Why isn't it simply the total number of SEP_11 computers? If a site has 100 SEP_11 why does it matter if it has 0 SEP_12 or 1000 SEP_12? Do you want the ratio of SEP_11/SEP_12? I'm not even sure this is Data Science...

Comment: @Spacedman I wasn't sure if this was the best forum to post, I was looking more for Data Analysis forum .... I think ratio might be a solution ... thinking ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way of visualizing this is to have the number of computers on the Y-axis and the size of the dots representing the percentages. The categories (or sites in your case) can be represented on the X-axis. The image below shows an example where the Y-axis represents a continuous value (can be mapped to number of computers in your case), the X-axis represents a discrete value (can be mapped to sites in your case), and the size of the dots represents another attribute (like percentage in your case). I have used the `R` package `ggplot2` for this. [image]

Comment: `R`? This is new to me, seems interesting!

Comment: @SohniMahiwal If you like the answer, please consider up voting/ accepting it. If you'd like, I could send you the script to produce this image.

Comment: I need 15 reputation or more to vote up